# Yandex Storage — Как задать путь до файла в облаке используя функцию сервеса Serverless Function?

Tags: python, облако, storage

Написал функцию на **Python**, в ней необходимо обратиться к файлу, который лежит в хранилище **Object Storage**. Не могу указать путь к хранилищу. Как функции получить доступ к хранилищу?
Для соединения с хранилищем использовал библиотеку **boto3**, она позволяет получить удаленный доступ к изображению, если запускать у себя на компьютере, но не способна получить этот доступ при вызове посредством **Serverless Functions**. Речь идет о строке `s3.upload_file('panda.jpg', 'testimages', 'panda1.jpg')`, тут если запускать на компьютере, то функция берет файл с компьютера и копирует его в яндекс хранилище. Однако та же строка не работает в **Serverless Functions**, так как не знает где искать файл *panda.jpg* чтобы в последствии скопировать в хранилище, а находится этот самый файл по адресу https://storage.yandexcloud.net/testimages/original/panda.jpg – файл лежит в папке *original* в бакете *testimages*.